# How to get random Decimal number from range?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, decimal

I'm looking for a way how to generate random `Decimal` number within some range. For example -

```
>>> random.choice(range(Decimal(1.55,3.89)))

>>> 1.89
```

Is it possible to do that with random? I want to preserve 2 decimal places.

```
random.choice(range(Decimal(1.55,3.89)))
```

returns `>>> 0`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `random.randrange()` like this:

```
import random
import decimal

decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(155, 389))/100
```

And then use `float()` to get your desired output:

```
>>> float(decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(155, 389))/100)
3.14
>>> float(decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(155, 389))/100)
1.91
```

As mentioned by @jsbueno in the comment, you can use generated numbers in formatted strings without converting them to floats:

```
>>> '{}'.format(decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(155, 389))/100)
'3.85'
```

You may need to use just `float()` like below:

```
>>> float(random.randrange(155, 389))/100
2.38
>>> float(random.randrange(155, 389))/100
3.72
```

**Note:**

In `random.randrange(155, 389)`, `155` is included in the range, but `389` is not, if you want to include `389`, you should use `random.randrange(155, 390)`. This is mentioned by @mhawke in the comments below.

Comment: @etanany Interesting solution. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if OP wants to include the endpoint of the range or not. If they do then use `random.randrange(155, 390)` or use `randint(155, 389)` which will include both endpoints.

Comment: @mhawke you mean `random.randrange(156, 388)`?

Comment: "float"  to get the desired output will get the wrong output, maybe more often than not - except when one wants to see the internal `repr` of the number as digits only. That is why it works on the example. On real code one most likely will just pass the Decimal object itself directly to be formatted as a string - either for screen output or for being recorded in a file.

Comment: @jsbueno I edited my answer to include this, thanks :)

Comment: @ettanany. Do I? `randrange(156, 388)` will exclude 155, 388 and 389 from the range. I'm suggesting that if the OP wants to include 155 and 389 that they need to compensate for the behaviour of `randrange()`.

Comment: @mhawke I did not read your comment well, sorry you wrote include not exclude.

Comment: @mhawke I added it above. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You could generate an integer in the range 100x your range, then divide by 100. Would save importing Decimal, and you wouldn't have to deal with cutting down on significant figures as you would with floats.

```
>>> import random

>>> random_decimal = random.randint(155, 389)/100
>>> print(random_decimal)
2.12
```

Or to output more values:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
>>>    print(random.randint(155, 389)/100)
2.69
3.84
3.53
3.87
1.56
2.12
2.7
2.4
3.31
3.28
```

Comment: The question is a duplicate and this answer is a duplicate from that thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972438/how-to-get-random-decimal-number-from-range

Comment: This is fine for Python 3, however, OP is using Python 2 in which `/` is integer division. The result will not be as you expect. Perhaps add a `from __future__ import division` at the top of the file, or divide by a float: `random.randint(155, 389)/100.0`.